# "This item's size is 36dp x 36dp. Consider making this touch target 48dp wide and 48dp high or larger"

Tags: android-layout

An Android layout has this button:

```
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonHome"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:minWidth="48dp"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_lens_24"
                    android:onClick="@{(v)->playVideoActivity.onClick(v)}"
                    android:contentDescription="Home"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
                    />
```

Why does Android Studio give the following error?

```
This item's size is 36dp x 36dp. Consider making this touch target 48dp wide and 48dp high or larger.
```

[image]

I don't know where it gets "36dp x 36dp". Could anyone shed some light on this?